# The direction of friction in rolling without slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

I know there are multiple SE questions talking about this subject but I still don't understand:
If I have three balls as seen in the picture, what is the direction of friction on each ball if:

1. No forces are applied on the first ball except gravity and N in the Y axis (I don't about friction, that's why I'm asking)
2. Some force passing through the COM is applied on the ball
3. Some force **not** passing through the COM is applied on the ball.

In the 3rd case, does it matter where the force is applied or how big it is?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force of friction in rolling without slipping](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282866/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with case 3

> Some force not passing through the COM is applied on the ball.

Let the mass of the ball be $M$, the radius of the ball be $R$, and let the external force $F_E$ be applied at position $r$ where $r=R$ is the top of the ball, $r=0$ is the center of the ball, and $r=-R$ is the bottom of the ball where it touches the ground. The external force $F_E$ points to the right and the friction force $F_F$ points to the left, the ball has a linear acceleration $a$ to the right and an angular acceleration $\alpha$ clockwise.

By Newton's 2nd law we have $F_E-F_F=M a$. Then since the moment of inertia about the center of the ball is $I=\frac{2}{5}MR^2$ we have $F_E r + F_F R = \frac{2}{5}MR^2 \alpha$. And the no-slip condition gives $a=R \alpha$. We have three equations so we can slove for $F_F$ and $a$ while eliminating $\alpha$. Doing so we get: $$F_F=\frac{F_E}{7R}(2R-5r)$$ $$a=\frac{5 F_E}{7MR}(R+r)$$

The one that is interesting for you is the first equation. If we plot it we get

[image: Frictional force as a function of the external force position]

where positive numbers are forces to the left. Note that at $r>0.4 R$ the friction force is negative so actually points to the right (forward)! So for 3 the direction of the frictional force does matter where the external force is applied, although the magnitude of the external force only affects the magnitude of the friction force, not its direction.

Now we can look at case 2

> Some force passing through the COM is applied on the ball

Substituting $r=0$ we get $F_F=\frac{2}{7}F_E>0$ so the frictional force points to the left.

Finally, for case 1

> No forces are applied on the first ball

Substituting $F_E=0$ we get $F_F=0$ so unsurprisingly there is no frictional force in case 1.

Comment: In the 3rd case (first one you addressed), How did you know that friction is to the left? Is that a fact regardless of what F external is? How can it be calculated? And later on you actually find out that for some values of "r" it is positive and for some it is negative. Was choosing the friction in the negative direction at the beginning an arbitrary choice?

Comment: Also, you get some strange results if r = -R, in that case from the equation for "a" you get that a=0. And from the first equation why is there a point that makes the ball have no friction at all (as seen in the fraph)

Comment: That is a lot of additional questions. I didn’t know it was to the left. I just assumed it was to the left and then wrote down the resulting equations. If the solution is positive then my guess was correct, and if the solution is negative then my guess was wrong and it points to the right. It isn’t important to guess right, just to make an arbitrary choice and then write all of your equations consistent with that choice.

Answer (score 2):

yes, It matters

1. where the force is applied. 
   for eg, if force is applied above z>r then the torque(analogue of newton second law) will be in opposite direction to the torque if the force applied above the height r (radius of the object).
2. And also how big it is
   let's suppose that the torque by force f (assuming the force is applied at z>r) is bigger than the torque applied by friction then it will try to rotate the object in a clockwise direction. It also decides the moving direction of object. 
   and if the condition for rolling is not satisfied by object (given in answer by user777777) then object is slipping at that moment.

[image: Rolling object]

[image: case 1]

Comment: I don't follow the last figure - if friction acts on the point of contact, the ball will roll, so I don't see why the top portion is labelled "no rolling". Similarly, if there's no friction force, the ball's rotation is independent of its linear motion, allowing it to slide freely without rolling at all. Are those labels backwards?

Comment: Initially, the ball has velocity Vo and angular velocity zero so the friction will try to reduce the velocity of the object and increase its angular velocity until the condition v=wr is satisfied. I don't think that ball rotation will be independent of linear motion in absence of frictional force (in case there is other force acting on it) but yes it would slide freely in the absence of any torque.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, assuming perfectly rigid bodies, the ball will continue to roll indefinitely. There is no friction and the net force acting on the ball is zero. The equation $v = r \omega$ is satisfied (or else there will be friction).

In the second and third scenarios, the ball will have a net acceleration. Newton's Second Law still applies: $F - F_f = ma$, where $F$ is the applied force and $F_f$ is the friction.

Additionally, the rotational analog of Newton's Second Law reads $F_f r + Fs = I_{CM} \alpha$, where $r$ is the radius, $s$ is the perpendicular distance of $F$ from the center, and $\alpha$ is its angular acceleration. (In the second scenario, $s = 0$.)

If the ball rolls without slipping, then the condition $a = r \alpha$ also holds.

Comment: How do you know that its minus friction and not plus?

Comment: @snatchysquid The friction acts in the opposite direction of the applied force. This is because the point of contact tries to move forward together with the rest of the ball but is stopped by friction. This applies torque and is what causes the ball to start rolling.

Comment: Yet Dale in his answer showed that sometimes this isn't the case.

Comment: @snatchysquid Yes, because when the force is applied too far away from the center, the ball's angular acceleration multiplied by its radius will (momentarily) exceed its linear acceleration. This causes the point of contact to attempt to move backwards relative to the ground and thus the friction will instead be forward.

Comment: Understood, thank you. So thinking intuitively could help but I may simply look at the equation and they don't lie.